# Mistakenly made CHMOD on root in El capitan

Tags: unix

I am using a Mac Book Pro with El Capitan installed. Yesterterday I was trying to change a file permission and I made a very big mistake.

This is the command I issued

```
  `sudo chmod -R 777 /`
```

After issuing the command the system began to give many system errors. I restarted my laptop and now it keeps stack at the apple logo with the progress bar.

I have been able to go to the single user mode, buh I dnt know how to get the laptop to boot normally.

Anybody with an idea on this can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should definitevely check this post about your problem [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201560). (Apple's Repair disk permissions with Disk Utility)

I don't think it will repair everything though...

Comment: It would be probably easier to backup everything and do a clean reinstall.
If you can't backup files the easiest way, try starting up from a recovery partition and cloning the main OS X drive from Disk Utility.